# Which is the most memory effective way to implements an iteration statement?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I know that there are ways to know the cost of cycle or an iteration statement, but I want to know 2 things:

**1st.**
Which of these two listing is more cost effective? (or if there are a better approach, I'm all ears):

**UPDATE:** The question then goes: Wich of the 2 of them will do proper use of the memory/GC? 
Keep in mind that, the "values" of `reqObj` and `resObj` are not going to be necessary for the next loop.

```
for (TransactionLog transactionLog : transactionLogList) {
 RequestObj reqObj = new RequestObj();
 ResponseObj resObj;
 try {

  //do things with these 2 babes and the transactionLog

 } catch (WhateverException ex) {
  log.error("Error in XYZ while doing whatever", ex);
  //execute code without throwing anything up
 } finally {
  reqObj = null;
  resObj = null;
 }
}
```

**or**

```
RequestObj reqObj = new RequestObj();
ResponseObj resObj;
for (TransactionLog transactionLog : transactionLogList) {
 try {
  //do things with these 2 babes and the transactionLog

 } catch (WhateverException ex) {
  log.error("Error in XYZ while doing whatever", ex);
  //execute code without throwing anything up
 } finally {
  //do something
 }
}
```

**and 2nd.** 
Where I can find a good place/book/site to learn this "algorithms best practice" and the function O(letter) to calculate the interation's statement cost?

PD: Sorry for my English... he's not very good looking. xD

Comment: In the first one you’re creating a `new RequestObj()` each time in the loop. In the second one you’re reusing it. You can’t compare completely different things.

Comment: Did you try to profile the two code snaps? If not - use the neater version (the 1st, but drop the nullifying in `finally`), and change it if there is significant performance issue. As a general rule of thumb: **Use the more readable code, unless you can show it is significantly inefficient comparing to the alternative**

Comment: the first one won't compile because the objects in the finally are out of scope

Comment: Option 2 is more efficient because you don't create a new object in every loop. But you should be careful, because if you reference reqObj from some things you create inside the loop, they will reference always the same object.

Comment: Well that's not a different style to do it but has completely different results. #1 modifies the same object all the time while #2 creates a new instance for each iteration. #1 nulls both fields while #2 does not guarantee that (which does not matter in this example because they fall out of scope eventually).

Comment: `babes`? Now I've seen everything

Comment: @NathanHughes yeah, thanks, that was a typo when editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local objects is clearer, less error prone, and such objects get handled well by the garbage collector. For reusable objects like a StringBuilder you could clear in every cycle instead of doing new StringBuilder I was surprised it holds too (said someone).

Just as setting to null is a beginner's signature.

Answer (score -1):

If `RequestObj` and `ResponseObj` are `AutoCloseable` (or you implement them as such), then you should consider using the **try-with-resources** block available with Java 7. It takes care of any cleanup that they require, or that you want, without the extra `finally` (or an additional catch in the `finally`, for that matter; those exceptions are suppressed).

```
try( RequestObj reqObj = new RequestObj(); ResponseObj resObj = ... ) {
  // Do stuff

} catch (WhateverException ex) {
  log.error("Error in XYZ while doing whatever", ex);
  // execute code without throwing anything up
} 

// No finally block required
```

You shouldn't worry about the GC/Memory issues as much as that seems to be premature optimization in your case. It's better to keep your code clean and readable.

For more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm working with java 6, but I'm going to keep this in mind for future references.